# How to open a Node.JS terminal in VS Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, terminal

How can I open a Node.JS terminal in the Visual Studio Code integrated terminal? I'm doing a tutorial to learn Angular and in the video the guy types in the command `ng serve`, but for me it says "command not recognized".

I noticed that my terminal it says PowerShell but on his it says node, so I thought maybe that's why it's not recognizing the command for me. But upon clicking the dropdown box to select node the option is not there for me. I do have Node.JS running but the terminal **option is not available** in VS Code.

[image: Node.JS terminal not available]

Comment: It says `ng` command is not recognized? Have you globally installed Angular's CLI?

Comment: @Sam not totally sure about that. I did run npm install, which as far as I know installed all the dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install the Angular CLI. I went to the [Angular website](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local) and found instructions. I just entered the command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

in the terminal and it installed. Then when I ran the command `ng serve` the terminal automatically switched over to node.

Thanks to Sam for asking if I had installed!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for Command Prompt. Click Select Default Shell and choose cmd prompt and it should work now

Comment: Tried but didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion